# simple registration page in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registration

I have the following code for the registration page:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require("mysqli.php"); 
?>
<html>

<head>

<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

if ( $_POST['registerbtn']){
 function add_member(){
 global $db_obj;
 $uid=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['uid']);      // (A)
 $last=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['last']);
 $first=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['first']);
 $email=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
 $pass=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['passwd']);  // (B)
 $query="INSERT INTO member VALUES ('$uid','$last','$first', '$email', PASSWORD('$pass'))"; // (D)
 return ($db_obj->query($query));                    // (E)
 echo "Your acount has been created!";

}}


else
{
$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>
<table>

<tr>
<td>uid:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='uid' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>last:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='last' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<td>first:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='first' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='email' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='pass' value=''/></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register'/></td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>";
echo $form;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and it is not working with me, what is my problem? I have created the member table in my local host as the following:

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE member

( uid varchar(10),
last varchar(25) NOT NULL,
first varchar(15) NOT NULL,
email varchar(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
passwd varbinary(48) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

and when I press the register button nothing shows with me.
any hints or advice please?

edited:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.8.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 01, 2014 at 12:36 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-log
-- PHP Version: 5.3.3

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `###`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `member`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `uid` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `last` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `first` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varbinary(48) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

---

login.php

```
<html>
<?php require("mysqli.php"); ?>
<head>

<title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

if ( $_POST['loginbtn']){
function authenticate($uid, $pass)
{global $db_obj;
$userid=$db_obj->escape_string($uid);
$pass=$db_obj->escape_string($pass);
$query="SELECT * FROM member WHERE uid =’$uid’"
. " AND passwd = PASSWORD(’$pass’)";
if ( ($result = $db_obj->query($query)) && $result->num_rows == 1 )
{ return $uid; }
else
{ return ""; }
}
}

else

$form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
<table>

<tr>
<td>uid:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='uid' value=''/></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='pass' value=''/></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>";
echo $form;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gotta call the function, at the moment you are just defining a function but not calling it

Comment: Hacking together an application this way is going to be extremely error prone and tedious. You'd be better served by picking up a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) and following the examples described in it. Most have some kind of user login module either built-in, or easily added. Composing your queries using string concatenation and not really encrypting your passwords are just two fundamental but serious problems to the approach you're taking here.

Comment: Consider using actual columns to insert into and not hoping it's going to land in the right holes. Don't you just love shooting an 18-hole at midnight? Try actual columns `"INSERT INTO member (uid,last,first, email, pass) VALUES ('$uid','$last','$first', '$email', PASSWORD('$pass'))"`

Comment: Your SQL table creating code is invalid, for another thing.

Comment: All these comments are correct. Firstly, when posting the data, you're merely creating the function add_member. Secondly I would not use this code in a production environment. Use a framework to achieve what you're after, believe me -we don't need more security holes based on the "that'll be fine" development method. Thirdly, never assume anything (Fred's comment), always code as if the person who's gonna use the system wants to break it.

Comment: why I am not able to see the values in my database? I changed my insert as you mentioned Fred but still not working

Comment: tadman, I am just practcing how to do this. I made another secure code in different why but I need this code to work with me

Comment: You need to match your column names. My example was just that; an example. @user3483167 `"INSERT INTO member (uid,last,first, email, passwd) VALUES ('$uid','$last','$first', '$email', PASSWORD('$pass'))"` and

Comment: I made the change Fred, but it is not working

Comment: How are you calling your `add_member()` function?

Comment: Plus, instead of `if($_POST['registerbtn']){` you should be using `if(isset($_POST['registerbtn'])){`

Comment: actually I do not have any background about this point, I just took the code from my book.

Comment: yes I tried this before the "if(isset($_POST['registerbtn']))" but the code is still not working

Comment: I tested your code without the function and it worked perfectly. However, the `PASSWORD` function I don't have, but it did work. So, just comment out the function and one of the closing braces for it.

Comment: I commented the add member function and I got the following error:


Warning: mysqli::escape_string() [mysqli.escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\AppServ\www\hw3\register.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli::escape_string() [mysqli.escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\AppServ\www\hw3\register.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli::escape_string() [mysqli.escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\AppServ\www\hw3\register.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli::escape_string() [mysqli.escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\AppServ\www\hw3\register.php on line 22

Comment: However, you will need to change `$_REQUEST['passwd']` to `$_REQUEST['pass']` because of the `<input type='password' name='pass' value=''/>` not a match. How are you using this function, where is it? `PASSWORD('$pass')`

Comment: yes I made the changes, but I have the warnings now.

Comment: I need to know what the `PASSWORD()` function is, do you have it in another file?

Comment: PASSWORD('$pass') = type of encryption as written in my book

Comment: Ok. I will post an answer below that you can try. Follow the instructions in there. I will also place my version of the query and commented out your old one, so you can test it.

Comment: ok I hope it will work fine with me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which worked for me, minus the `PASSWORD` function which I don't know how/where you're using. It is commented out in a query line of code.

Instead of using your `require("mysqli.php");` just replace the `xxx` below with your login credentials for the time being.

Affected lines have been commented out.

I also changed `<form action='./register.php' method='post'>` to `<form action='' method='post'>`

The entire code works from the same page.

There are comments inside the code for you to read.

```
<?php
// session_start();
// require("mysqli.php"); 

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";


$db_obj = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db_obj->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db_obj->connect_error . ']');
}

if($db_obj->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect [' . $db_obj->connect_errno . ']');
}


?>
<html>

<head>

<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

if ($_POST['registerbtn']){
// function add_member(){ // commented out
 global $db_obj; // fill in credential on top instead.
 $uid=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['uid']);      // (A)
 $last=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['last']);
 $first=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['first']);
 $email=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
 $pass=$db_obj->escape_string($_REQUEST['pass']);  // (B)

 // Test line of code without the PASSWORD function
 $query="INSERT INTO member (uid,last,first, email, passwd) VALUES ('$uid','$last','$first', '$email', '$pass')"; // (D)

 // Comment out once the above test worked, then comment out the line above
 // $query="INSERT INTO member (uid,last,first, email, passwd) VALUES ('$uid','$last','$first', '$email', PASSWORD('$pass'))"; // (D)

 // return ($db_obj->query($query)); // (E)
 echo "Your account has been created!";

}
// } commented out. Used for add_member() function


else
{
$form = "<form action='' method='post'>
<table>

<tr>
<td>uid:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='uid' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>last:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='last' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<td>first:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='first' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='email' value=''/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='pass' value=''/></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register'/></td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>";
echo $form;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```